# How to obtain the content of any running apps, like in zoom or Alt+Tab

Tags: c#, winapi

As you see in this screenshot, zoom is able to get the content of running apps. The thumbnails are even "live".

[image]

It is the same thing I suppose when you use `Alt+Tab` : you have the "live" content of all running apps.

How can I obtain the same thing in my own program : obtain the content of any running app ? My need is only to have a snapshot of an application. But "who can do more can do less" I suppose.

Comment: @RaymondChen : do you think that Desktop Windows Manager is the only way ?

Comment: how many different ways do you need?